# Can't get array by $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-resource

Can't get array by `$resource`. Can you help me? When I use `$http` all is well

I have error in console:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js:597:29
at forEach (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:327:18)
at angular.module.provider.$get.Resource.(anonymous function).$http.then.value.$resolved (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js:595:19)
at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11616:81)
at http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11702:26
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12797:28)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12609:31)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12901:24)
at done (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8487:45)
at completeRequest (http://127.0.0.1:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8703:7)
```

I created a factory with method

```
coeffsResource.factory("CoeffsResources",['$resource', 

function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/:action',{}, {
    get_all_coeffs: { method:'GET', isArray:false, params: {action: 'getAllRegionCoefficients'} },
    save_all_coeffs: { method:'POST', params: {action: 'storeAllRegionCoefficients'} },
    get_manufacturer: { method: 'GET', isArray:true, params: {action: 'getAllManufacturers'} },
    get_models: { method: 'GET', params: {action: 'getModels'} },
    get_classes: {method: 'GET', params: {action: 'getClassesConfig'} },
    get_regions: {method: 'GET', params: {action: 'getAllRegions'} },
    get_ages_config: {method: 'GET', params: {action: 'getAgesConfig'} },
    get_odometer: {method: 'GET', params: {action: 'getOdometersConfig'} },
    get_tax_config: {method: 'GET', params: {action: 'getTaxConfig'} }
  }, {stripTrailingSlashes: false})
}]);
```

Include factory in controller

```
angular.module('etachkaEvaluatorFrontendApp')
  .controller('CoeffCtrl', function($scope,  $http, $resource, $q, CoeffsResources) {

      var coeffsResourcesObject =  new CoeffsResources();
      coeffsResourcesObject.$get_manufacturer().then(function() {

      }, function() {

      })
})
```

Comment: Please add any error message you are getting.

Comment: Firts block of code in my question, it is my error in console

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread that completely. My bad.

Comment: Have you solved this? Was my suggestion able to help you?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you newing up a singleton? AngularJS Factories are not intended to work this way. See the [AngularJS service docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) for more information

> Angular services are:
>
> 1. Lazily instantiated – Angular only instantiates a service when an
>    application component depends on it.
> 2. Singletons – Each component
>    dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance
>    generated by the service factory.

Change your usage in `CoeffCtrl` to the following... (this also assumes you have correctly loaded the [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) module at some earlier point in your application)

```
.controller('CoeffCtrl', function($scope,  $http, $resource, $q, CoeffsResources) {
  CoeffsResources.$get_manufacturer().then(function() {

  }, function() {

  })
```

---

For a better understanding on factory behavior I have crafted two simple demos. Note that these are not intended to solve your issues in a copy/paste fashion - but to demonstrate what happens when we `new` an AngularJS factory.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lnt1hof/) - demo - correct

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dc4b2sLq/) - demo - incorrect - `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: It doesn't work too...
When I look to network in devtools, I get a response...
function-handler doesn't work((
And I used "new" in other project, it was good(

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to inject the ngResource dependency.

```
angular.module('etachkaEvaluatorFrontendApp', ['ngResource'])
```

Comment: nice find I overlooked that. I have a feeling there are a few issues with this question and we're identifying each. feedback will be necessary